# Using a local version of a Maven dependency in Visual Studio Code

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, dependency-management, snapshot

I have a Java Maven project company-publisher in Visual Studio Code. I have opened both projects as a workspace. I want to use a local version of a repository company-util I have as a dependency instead of the remote version. I have modified the POM for company-publisher to include 2.26-SNAPSHOT instead of 2.26.1. This matches the artifactID of company-util I want to use as a dependency.

In Eclipse all you need to do is open both repositories at once and change the POM of company-publisher to include project company-util as a dependency with -SNAPSHOT for the point version as I have done. Then I can update project and when I expand the Maven Dependencies of company-publisher I see company-util listed as a folder instead of a .jar. How would I go about doing this in Visual Studio Code? I'm not sure what Eclipse is doing behind the scenes to make that possible.

Here is the definition for the dependency:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>companyID</groupId>
        <artifactId>companyID-parent</artifactId>
        <version>17.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>company-util</artifactId>
    <version>2.26-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

and the inclusion of the dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>companyID</groupId>
            <artifactId>company-util</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I navigate to the war deployment created by running `mvn -U install` within the parent folder of company-publisher, navigate to WEB-INF/lib, I see company-util-2.26.1.jar. In the WAR created by eclipse, I see a company-util-2.26-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: In Eclipse this is called "Workspace resolution" and is part of the m2e plugin.

Answer (score 3):

To use local version of maven dependency add the following configuration into the settings.json file:

```
"java.configuration.maven.userSettings": "<path to maven settings.xml>"
```

Also enable snapshots to the pluginRepository where the jar is published

```
<pluginRepository>
  <id>repo_id</id>
  <url>some repo url</url>
  <snapshots>                                             
    <enabled>true</enabled>                                                                  
  </snapshots>
</pluginRepository>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is already possible in vscode. I just did the test with two java projects. When A references in pom.xml the exact version of B in the same workspace, vscode uses local project instead of jar in repository.
Do you use workspace definition in your vscode?

Comment: I added some extra info to my original post if you could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this [article](https://dev.to/wakeupmh/adding-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project-1h9n), it has multiple was to add local dependency independent of code editor.

One that worked for me is below

````xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mh.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-example-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/myCustomJAR.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>```
````